# Android Camera, Simultaneous Raw Preview and Raw TakePicture

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

So I'm working on something akin to a Camera app. It draws a live camera preview on a native OpenGL texture. If a button is pressed, a still image is captured (possibly at a higher res than the live preview) in its raw form.

Here is the general outline of my code. I am not showing less-relevant pieces for clarity. This a simplified situation where preview and still cap resolutions are identical.

```
void Setup(Activity a) {

  // .. snip ..

  mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(a);
  mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
  //put the surface off-screen
  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams alp = new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(8, 8, -8, -8); 
  a.addContentView(mSurfaceView, alp); //need this, otherwise surface is not created

  mCamera = Camera.open(miCameraId);
  mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);

  ConfigureCameraDefaults(640,480);
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------- //

void ConfigureCameraDefaults(int iX, int iY) {
  Camera.Parameters oParameters=mCamera.getParameters();

  oParameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
  oParameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
  oParameters.setPreviewSize(iX, iY); // for live preview
  oParameters.setPictureSize(iX, iY); // for still capture

  int bpp = ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(ImageFormat.NV21);
  int iBufSize = (int) (iX*iY*((float)bpp/8));
  mBuffer = new byte[iBufSize];
  mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);

  try {
      mCamera.setParameters(oParameters);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      // .. snip ..
  }
}

void startPreview() {
  mCamera.startPreview();
}

void stopPreview() {
  mCamera.stopPreview();
}

void takePicture() {
  mCamera.takePicture(null, this, null, null); //2nd is the raw callback
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------- //

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  // -- at this point the buffer is in a safe state, until it is added again
  onPreviewFrame_native(data);

  // -- make buffer writable again
  mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
}

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  onStillCapture_native(data);
  mCamera.startPreview(); //otherwise preview will stop
}
```

Ok, so now the questions. When `takePicture()` is not called, everything functions according to plan. Preview frames arrive, they're processed, buffer is re-queued. However, if I `startPreview()` then do `takePicture()`, the picture callback gets a null data array. Every time. Google docs have this to say about `takePicture()`:

`The raw callback occurs when the raw image data is available (NOTE: the data will be
null if there is no raw image callback buffer available or the raw image callback
buffer is not large enough to hold the raw image).`

This is not entirely clear to me, as:

1. There is no function to set buffer for still capture, only for prevew frames
2. Even if the same buffer is used for both still caps and preview frames, I do have a buffer queued up.
3. Adding a second buffer (identical to the preview buffer) specifically for still caps has absolutely no effect
4. Preview has to be started in order for `takePicture()` to be a valid call.

Am I missing something obvious? Or are we not allowed to get raw frames from video and still at the same time? There is nothing in the docs about this whatsoever. I've looked at the camera source as well, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I've tried using a different color format for the still, unsetting preview callback before taking a picture, adding a second buffer, requeueing the second buffer, setting surface holder to push type, and some other things that I am failing to recall at the moment. None made any difference.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to get the raw image. The method `addCallbackBuffer` is only used by the preview callbacks. There is another method `addRawImageCallbackBuffer` which is supposed to do what you want. It is public but not exported, so you cannot call it directly. You can call it like this:

```
    try {
        final Method addRawImageCallbackBuffer =
                camera0.getClass()
                       .getDeclaredMethod("addRawImageCallbackBuffer",
                                          byte[].class);
        addRawImageCallbackBuffer.invoke(camera0, new byte[100000000]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RNG", "Error", e);
    }
```

but on my Nexus 5 it still returns `null` on the callback, so I think it is simply not supported.